# Storing const char* gives me random characters

Tags: c++, string, struct, char

Okay so basically i have a struct like this

```
struct person{
   const char* name;
   const char* about_me;
   const char* mom_name;
   const char* age;
};
```

And then in order to make my code versatile i have

```
struct Person PersonAsArray[MAX_ARRAY - 1];
```

And then i have a file that reads in a bunch of stuff and eventually i parse it. but when i parse it i get a `std::string` so i gotta convert it to a `const char*` so heres some more of my code:

```
getline(file, line);
//break the line up into 2 parts (because in the file its "name=John")
//these two parts are called id and value
if(id == "name"){
    const char* CCvalue = value.c_str();
    cout << CCvalue << endl; // its fine here
    PersonAsArray[i].name = CCvalue; //i is incremented each time i need a new struct
}
if(id == "age"){
    PersonAsArray[i].age = atoi(value.c_str());
}
//and some more of this stuff... eventually i have

cout << PersonAsArray[0].name << endl;
cout << PersonAsArray[0].about_me << endl;
cout << PersonAsArray[0].mom_name << endl;
cout << PersonAsArray[0].age << endl;
```

but when i finally cout everything, i end up with something that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmGcZ.png). I'm just a little curious on whats going on and why its giving me symbols? and its not always the same symbols. Sometimes i get the smiley face, sometimes i dont even get the whole row of rectangles. I have no idea what im doing and its probably some major flaw in my coding. But this also happens when i do something like this

```
string hi = "hello"
for(i = 0; hi[i] != '\0'; i++){
    char x = hi[i];
    string done = "";
    if(x == 'h') done += "abc";
    if(x == 'e') done += "zxc";
    if(x == 'l') done += "aer";
    if(x == 'o') done += "hjg";
    cout << done;
}
```

I think i remember getting these flower like shapes and i think i even saw chinese characters but again they were not consistent even if i didnt change anything in the program, if i ran it several times, i would see several different combination of symbols and sometimes no symbols would appear.

Answer (score 1):

You did not read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)!

The value returned by `std::string::c_str()` does not live forever.

> The pointer obtained from `c_str()` may be invalidated by:
>
> - Passing a non-const reference to the string to any standard library function, or
> - Calling non-const member functions on the string, excluding `operator[]`, `at()`, `front()`, `back()`, `begin()`, `rbegin()`, `end()` and `rend()`.

The destructor is one such "non-const member function".

Once the pointer is invalidated, *you cannot use it*. When you try, you either get the data stored at some arbitrary place in memory (your computer's futile attempts to make sense of that data, as if it were text, are resulting in the flowers and Chinese characters you describe) or other unpredictable, bizarre symptoms.

Unfortunately you did not present a [complete, minimal testcase](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we have no idea how `value` *really* fits into your code, but it's clear that it does not survive intact between your "its fine here" and your problematic code.

Don't store the result of `std::string::c_str()` long-term. There's no need to, and it's rarely useful to.

**tl;dr Make `person` store `std::string`s, not dangling pointers.**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have something like

```
{
  std::string value;
  // fill value
  PersonsAsArray[i].name = value.c_str();
}
```

Now, `value` is a local variable which gets destroyed upon exiting the scope in which it is declared. You store the pointer to its internal data to a `.name` but you are not copying it so after destruction it points to garbage.

You should have a `std::string name` field instead that `const char*`, that will handle copying and retaining the content by itself and its copy assignment operator or allocate memory for the `const char*` manually, for example through `strdup`.